Should I merge tokens based on Named Entity Recognition?
I am working on an NLP project for sentiment analysis and I am using SpaCy to tokenize sentences. As I was reading the documentation, I learned about NER and I try to find if it can help me in tokenization.
To speak with examples:
Let's say we have a sentence "Let's not forget that Apple Pay in 2014 required...". When I tokenize it, it breaks into [Let, 's, not, forget, that, Apple, Pay, in, 2014, required, ...].
My main question is, would it be a good technique to merge tokens that represent an entity, into one? For example, "Apple" and "Pay" would become "Apple_Pay". My thinking is when training a classifier, not to confuse the organization "Apple" with the fruit "apple" (same for other words).
Would this improve performance or wouldn't worth the effort?
